# sql call function multiple times in a loop. postgres 8.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that has 'key' variable as an argument.

I want to call this function for a range of key values.

I tried this, didn't work...

```
BEGIN
for i IN 773..775 LOOP
  test_count(i);
end LOOP;
end;
```

SQL error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "for"
LINE 2: for i IN 773..775 LOOP

Comment: `didn't work` is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: SQL error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "for"
LINE 2: for i IN 773..775 LOOP

Comment: @a_horse meant you should update your question and mention the error message. If it's in the comments anyone trying to answer your question will have to read every comment to find bits and pieces of info.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this would be easier in version 9.0 or 9.1 (or 9.2, which should be released later this summer). Version 8.3 will hit end-of-life in about 8 months. When you upgrade, you should strongly consider jumping over 8.4 and 9.0 and going to 9.1 or later.

Answer (score 3):

@Mihai already explained that you cannot run procedural elements outside of a function or anonymous code block with `DO`.

Your syntax would still fail, because you cannot call a function *anywhere* without taking care of the returned value(s). If you want to discard possible return values(s) use [**`PERFORM`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) in a function like this (works with PostgreSQL 8.3):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

FOR i IN 773 .. 775
LOOP
   PERFORM test_count(i);
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL 8.3 cannot run anonymous procedures/ functions or create variables outside of a procedure/ function.

The [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-do.html) construct was added as support for anonymous procedures as of version `9.0`.

You should run your code inside a function. Because the error message you are receiving states that `FOR` is an unexpected keyword in a global context.

Comment: It can, just not that outdated version he is using.

Comment: I'm updating the answer i forgot to mention the `DO` construct in 9+ indeed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Wait what version of PG *does* that work on?

Comment: I've already statet that in my answer as well as my comment here. The version is > 9.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Major versions in PostgreSQL are denominated by the first two parts of the number, i.e. `8.4`, `9.0`, `9.1`, ... Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as "version 9". Read up about [PostgreSQL versioning](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) here. The DO statement was announced in the [release notes for 9.0 here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-0.html#AEN110462).

Comment: My bad indeed, i mentioned 9+ and > 9 in the comments suggesting that any version above 9.0 has that feature but the answer only says version 9. I'll update

Answer (score 0):

Use a **record** type for your keys

```
DO $BODY$
DECLARE tmp_row record;
BEGIN

  FOR tmp_row IN (SELECT key from my_keys_table)
   LOOP
     PERFORM test_function(tmp_row.key);
  END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$;
```